# Issue with Require IP directive Apache Debian

Tags: apache, debian

I had a working config using  on Apache 2.4 Debian Buster. However I cannot tell what is causing the errors because the system is actually interpreting the directive and denying access based on it as opposed to allow the access.

```
<location /restricted>
     <RequireAny>
#Admin1
        Require ip 192.168.172.241
     </RequireAny>
</location>
```

This location is a reverse proxy to an internal node so the only Directory in the config for the virtualhost is:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In the vhost error log I get the following message:

```
[authz_core:error] [pid 20896] [client 192.168.172.241:58346] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: proxy:http://[internal.ip:port]
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself to be having one of the most basic issues in the history of ever. I modified at some point the file with the ACL configuration in Notepadd++ in Windows through SSH SCP connection. For whatever reason it created a Microsoft carriage and EOL on the line with the IP that invalidated the ACL "only" for that entry. Lesson learned.